# Multiple where clauses on the same column with a many to many relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

**The setup.**

I am trying to implement a complex search query via RoR's `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

So far the code inside the `index` action code looks as follows:

```
query = Member.all
query = query.search(params[:q])
query = query.includes(:structures)
query = query.with_structure(params[:party_id])
query = query.with_structure(params[:assembly_id])

@members = query.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

The idea behind the code is that I get all Members and then remove members when a filter is active. `search` and `with_structures` are custom class methods inside which the `where` clauses are performed.

*Sidenote: Because of this, if your solution involves using `arel`, make sure that you show me how to convert AREL::NODES back into ActiveRecord::Relation*

My DB looks as follows:

[image]

**A member can change his position within a structure, thus he/she can have many participations with one/the same structure.**

**The problem**

When both `party` and `assembly` filters are active the query returns nothing, because it performs multiple where clauses on the same column.

**What I tried**

```
Member.joins(:structures)
.where(structures: { id: [1303, 1181] })
.group("members.id").count
```

or if you prefer the SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, members.id AS members_id
FROM "members"
INNER JOIN "participations" ON "participations"."member_id" = "members"."id"
INNER JOIN "structures" ON "structures"."id" = "participations"."structure_id"
WHERE "structures"."id" IN (1303, 1181)
GROUP BY members.id
HAVING count(*)>1
```

This doesn't work, because many records have a count > 1, but are part of only one of the two structures and using OUTER LEFT JOIN doesn't help either.

I also tried using `arel`, but I was not able to convert back to ActiveRecord. I tried using `q1.intersect q2`.

**What I want**

I want to be able to apply both where statements without them cancelling each other out. I want to be able to write something in like this:

```
query = Member.all
q1 = query.with_structure(params[:party_id])
q2 = query.with_structure(params[:assembly_id])
query = q1.intersect q2
```

Thank you in advance, and please do not hasitate to ask quetions if something is not clear. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join to participations twice, once for each id.

```
 from members m join participation p1
 on m.id = p1.member_id and p1.structure_id = 1303
 join participation p2 on m.id = p2.member_id and p2.structure_id = 1181
```

I'm not sure if you need to join to structures, because you don't appear to be selecting from it.

Comment: Hi Dan. I will test what you proposed and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi again. :) You are correct. Making multiple joins is the way to go. However I am still trying to figure out how to implement the code the most elegant way, this is - staying within the activerecord relation without using something like `Member.find_by_sql(sql code)`. This would be a last resort. I tried multiple times in the past to split the joins with the methods provided by rails without success. Member.joins(:participations).where("participations.structures_id" => 1303).joins(:participations).where("participations.structures_id" => 1181) has only one `joins` for rails :/

Answer (score 2):

I want to share with SO what I managed as a solution to the problem. I am not going to accept my own answer as THE answer, because @Dan Bracuk helped me a bit and it wouldn't be fair.

In the controller:

```
query = Member.all
query = query.search(params[:q])

ids = params.slice(:party_id, :assembly_id).values.delete_if { |v| v.blank? }.map { |v| v.to_i }
query = query.create_joins ids

@members = query.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

This is inside the members model:

```
def self.create_joins structure_ids
  if structure_ids.empty?
    all
  else
    structure_ids.each_with_index.map do |id, idx|
      joins("INNER JOIN 'participations' 'p#{idx}' ON 'p#{idx}'.'member_id' = 'members'.'id'")
      .where("p#{idx}.structure_id" => id).uniq
    end.reduce(:merge)
  end
end
```

The idea is that we create a separate join and query for every id that is inside `sructure_ids` and then we simply `merge` them together using the `reduce` method.